# How do I open a text file from a parent directory in Python?

Tags: python, file, directory, text-files, parent

I am trying to open a text file from a parent directory in Python. Here is the tree (simplified):

```
+ Project:
    - main.py
    + Source:
        + Documents:
            - hello.txt
        + Modules:
            - second.py
```

I am trying to read `hello.txt` from `second.py`.

Here is the problem line in `second.py`:

```
file = open('../Documents/hello.txt', 'r')
```

Returns Error: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../Documents/hello.txt'`

Comment: `..\Documents\hello.txt`?

Comment: @Jab - using two dots did not work

Comment: What is the working directory? If your code is running in `Project`, then you need to open `./Source/Documents/hello.txt`

Comment: @PranavHosangadi - ./Source/Documents/hello.txt works! Thank you. I realized my mistake. Please compose an answer with this line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relative paths are relative to the *working directory*. If you are running your code in the `Projects` directory, the path needs to be relative to that directory, so you need to `open('./Source/Documents/hello.txt')`

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the absolute path:

`file = open('/home/user/Project/Source/Documents/hello.txt`

Change the directory names upstream of Project to what you have set up.

Or if second.py is not going to move you can use relative path:

`file = open('../Documents/hello.txt')`

The '..' takes you to the parent directory and you can then drop down to Documents directory from there. You can also stack the '..'. For example you can get to `main.py` by using:

`file = open('../../main.py')`

Comment: you can only use a relative path correctly if you know the working directory.

Comment: I have tried opening using the relative path (that is what I prefer), but it still fails to open.

Comment: Because you don't know what your working directory is, and you are specifying the *wrong* relative path. The working directory is the one inherited from the shell, not necessarily the directory containing the script or file that defined the module.